# More parameters for geom_curve() function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Read the raw data

```
lat.actual.f.class<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/myplotdata.csv",h=T)
colnames(lat.actual.f.class)<-c("lat","long")
```

Create the limits of latitude based on each max longitude

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

class.1<-lat.actual.f.class %>%
  group_by(long) %>%
  summarise(max_lat = max(lat, na.rm = TRUE)) 
class.1<-as.data.frame(class.1)  
class.2<-cbind(class.1[,1],class.1$max_lat)
class.2<-cbind(class.2)
class.2<-as.data.frame(class.2)  
colnames(class.2)<-c("lat","long")
```

Visualization of longitude limits to the max latitude using `geom_curve()`:

```
ggplot(class.2, aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
                 geom_point(shape=16, show.legend = FALSE) +
                 geom_curve(aes(x=min(long),y=max(lat),xend = min(long), yend =min(lat)),data=class.2,, curvature = -0.9)
```

[image: myplot]

Not so nice and I'd like to draw a curve like the red line above. I make several changes in `curvature` without success, maybe I need something like x and y middle position.

Please, any ideas?

Comment: Idea: Make a fit of a model function to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first switch `long` and `lat` on the axes in the plot, use `geom_smooth()` to get the curve, and then use `coord_flip()` to flip the axes so `long` is back on the x-axis and `lat` is on the y-axis.

```r
ggplot(class.2, aes(x = lat, y = long)) +
    geom_point(shape = 16, show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_smooth(method = 'loess', col = 'red', se = FALSE) + 
    coord_flip()
```

[image: Plot]